# Vector space and Additive Identity

Tags: linear-algebra

If we consider P2( All polynomials in x of degree 2 as most)...

What is the additive Identity of P2? I get it is x+0=x  So, would it just be + 0 ?

The additive inverse of P(x) = ax^2 + bx +c is -ax^2-bx-c

Then if you let S be the set of all polynomials in P2, rx^2+rx, where r is a real number, is S a subspace of P2?

Comment: In your last line something seems to be off. You are saying S be the set of all polynomials in $P_2$...... then you are asking is S in $P_2$. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, is S a subspace of P2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try it. Define:

$$
P_2 = \{ax^2 + bx + c : a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\}
$$

This is a vector space under addition:

$$
(ax^2 + bx + c) + (a'x^2 + b'x + c') = (a+a')x^2 + (b+b')x + (c+c')
$$

$$
r(ax^2 + bx + c) = (ra)x^2 + (rb)x + (rc)
$$

Lets look at $S \subseteq P_2$

$$
S = \{rx^2 + rx + 0 : r \in \mathbb{R}\}
$$

If $S$ is a subspace, then $S$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Clearly, this is the case since $(rx^2 + rx + 0) + (r'x^2 + r'x + 0) = (r+r')x^2 + (r+r')x + 0$, and $c(rx^2 + rx + 0) = (cr)x^2 + (cr)x + 0$.

So, to answer your original question: Yes, it is a subspace. One way to think about these is to think of them as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Think of the polynomial with coefficients $a,b,c$ as the vector $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, with operations defined as usual. You may notice everything behaves the same way!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Use the test for subspace: if $\alpha, \beta \in S$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ (assuming the field of scalars is real numbers). Then $\alpha - \beta \in S$ and $c\alpha \in S$ (where $c \in \mathbb{R}$).

In this case $\alpha \in S$ means there exists $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha = ax^2+ax$, likewise $\beta=bx^2+bx$. Then
$$\alpha - \beta = (a-b)x^2+(a-b)x.$$
Since the coefficient of both $x$ and $x^2$ are same (and real numbers) therefore $\alpha - \beta \in S$. Now check closure under multiplication by a scalar.